# SQL table truncates when using a trigger to join. Require work around

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, left-join

I have two tables. One contains a list of employees and their information

```
EmployeeID  | Name  |  Start Date |HoursCF | HoursTaken
------------+-------+-------------+--------+------------
1           | Conor | 15/10/2018  | 0      |0
2           | Joe   | 01/05/2018  | 0      |0
3           | Tom   | 01/01/2019  | 0      |0
```

The other Contains Holiday Request put in by Employees

```
EmployeeID  | HoursTaken     |  
------------+----------------+
1           | 8              |     
2           | 16             |     
3           | 8              | 
2           | 8              |
1           | 16             |
```

I want it so when a new Holiday request is created,deleted,or updated on my holiday request table it updates on my employee table such as

```
EmployeeID  | Name  |  Start Date |HoursCF | HoursTaken
 -----------+-------+-------------+--------+------------
 1          | Conor | 15/10/2018  | 0      |24
 2          | Joe   | 01/05/2018  | 0      |24
 3          | Tom   |01/01/2019   | 0      |8
```

I have tried creating a view

```
CREATE VIEW vw_HoursTakenPerEmployee AS
SELECT e.[EmployeeID], 
       COALESCE(SUM(hr.[HoursTaken]), 0) AS HoursTaken
FROM [dbo].[Employees] e LEFT JOIN
     [dbo].[HolidayRequests] hr
      ON e.[EmployeeID] = hr.[EmployeeID]
GROUP BY e.[EmployeeID];
```

Ans then using a trigger to insert new data entered into the holiday request table into the employee table

```
ALTER trigger Inserttrigger on [dbo].[HolidayRequestForm]
after INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 
as
begin
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[HoursTakenPerEmployee]
INSERT INTO [dbo].[HoursTakenPerEmployee] ([EmployeeID],[HoursTaken])
SELECT * FROM vw_HoursTakenPerEmployee;
end
```

I know the problem is the truncate statement as it works fine if all the employees already have an entry in the holiday request table. If they don't, they get truncated from the employees table any time a new holiday request is made that does not belong to them.

Any Thoughts?

Comment: What is `v1`? Is it `vw_HoursTakenPerEmployee`? And is `HolidayRequestForm` really a separate table from `HolidayRequests`? The trigger doesn't seem to care about data in either the `inserted` pseudo-table *or* the `HolidayRequestForm` table. Typically you will want to just deal with the affected rows. If one employee submits a holiday request, why re-calculate everyone? This is like buying a new bike every time you have a flat tire.

Comment: Yes it is, sorry was switching around different views I was trying!

Comment: And what do you mean by an employee gets truncated from a table? I have to say that this process seems left of center. When you start truncating and repopulating inside a trigger it is a sign that something is not really designed quite right.

Comment: Why do you truncate the table ?

Comment: @Sean As in all the rows get deleted and then the trigger inserts the new data but if an employee has no holiday request put it, they get deleted from the employees table. I need to consider a re design of the process so?

Comment: Why do you need the separate table? All it has is the results of the view. Just query the view and drop the trigger, problem solved (and your system will thank you for all the resources you stop wasting maintaining a redundant copy of the data). Why would an employee get deleted from any table?

Comment: @Daniel To attempt to update it, I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: To update the most efficient is UPDATE ! Same the most efficient to insert some data is to use INSERT. :D

Comment: @Aaron I just thought it would of been easier to design (clearly not). The view does work, but I need the trigger for when a new request is put in so the Employee table updates!

Comment: I totally agree with @AaronBertrand. Don't physically store data, that can be calculated from already existing data. That bears the severe risk of inconsistencies. Drop the column `HoursTaken` in the employees table and extend that view to have all the columns from the employees table and the taken hours in it. Then use the view.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks, I think I'm really over complicating this

Comment: I still don't understand why you need to keep a count in a table when you can always get that count by joining to the view (or changing the view to include additional columns, as sticky bit mentioned, but that gets hard due to grouping).

Comment: `HoursTakenPerEmployee` is an other table than 2 displayed ? ?

Comment: I also don't understand how truncating HoursTakenPerEmployee deletes a row from the Employee table. I think you are not sharing all the code here. But it seems the biggest issue is that the tables are not well designed which is causing to go through all kinds of crazy gyrations to keep data correct.

Comment: @Daniel Yes to store data which would be then inserted into the Employees table. I understand now that's very unnecessary

Comment: I think the answer is given by @stickybit. You just need to do a view, no trigger.

Comment: @Daniel Okay cool, but will the employees table update if data is entered into the holiday request by just using a view?

Comment: Are you sure you want to **physically** store some redundant information ? You already have it easily from the view. Just need to change the query which display you table employees to display the view.

Comment: No I don't need to store it. I'm just a little confused on how to store the result of the view into the table of Employees?? I do need that data in there in order to create computed columns within that table.

Comment: You can add the computed columns to the view too.

Comment: @stickybit okay, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already done all the work:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_HoursTakenPerEmployee AS
SELECT e.*, 
       COALESCE(SUM(hr.[HoursTaken]), 0) AS HoursTaken
FROM [dbo].[Employees] e LEFT JOIN
     [dbo].[HolidayRequests] hr
      ON e.[EmployeeID] = hr.[EmployeeID]
GROUP BY e.[EmployeeID];
```

Drop the hours taken column from the EmployeeTable. Any time you want to know how many hours an employee took for holiday, query the view. The view query will be re-run every time the view is queried, so it will be up to date

Bear in mind your system will only work for a year. I recommend that you add a year indicator to your HolidayRequests table so you can give employees a new allowance every new fiscal/holiday year they're at the company.

Also, if an employee starts part way through a year, you can have the view calculate how many hours they're entitled to:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_HoursTakenPerEmployee AS
SELECT 
    e.*,
    hr.*, 
    DATEDIFF(HOUR, e.HolEntitleFrom, e.HolEntitleTo) / e.HolidayEntitlementHours as HoursEarnedSoFar, 
    COALESCE(hr.HoursTaken), 0) AS HoursTaken
FROM 
    (
        SELECT *,
            --change "Start Date" column name so it doesn't have a space in it!
            CASE WHEN [Start Date] < d.HolidayYearStart THEN d.HolidayYearStart ELSE [Start Date] END as HolEntitleFrom,
            CASE WHEN TerminationDate IS NULL THEN GetDate() ELSE TerminationDate as HolEntitleTo,
        FROM
            [dbo].[Employees]
            --useful constants can go here, like when holiday year starts from
            CROSS JOIN 
            (SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1, 1) as HolidayYearStart) d
    ) e
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT employeeid, HolidayYear, SUM(HoursTaken) AS HoursTaken
        FROM [dbo].[HolidayRequests] 
        GROUP BY EmployeeID, holidayyear
    ) hr
    ON hr.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID AND
       hr.holidayYear = YEAR(e.HolEntitleFrom) --this year's holiday requests
        ;
```

as an example..

- Put a HolidayYear column in HolidayRequests, to track which holiday year the request was made in. INT, data like 2018, 2019..
- Put a HolidayEntitlementHours in Employee to track how many holiday hours the emp gets this year (most places have a system where the amount of holiday increases for each full year of service so year on year). Float/decimal type.. Or make it something the view calculates from a basic allowance plus a time-in-service calculation
- Put a column for the terminationdate of an emp, so you can get an indication of whether they overspent their holidays (if your place allows to take more hours than have been earned so far). Imagine the emp took 20 days in jan, and then has to work a year to earn it. They hand in 1 months notice on 1 june. Setting a termination date of 1 july (about 6 months after the holiday entitlement start) would show them as having maximally earned 10 by the time they leave, so they need to pay back 10